# Python. Сохранение html файла

Tags: python

Решил в своего бота на aiogram добавить html отчет, и появилась проблема:

```
SyntaxError: f-string: invalid syntax
```

Код:

```
html = f"<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <style> html { background: rgb(35,28,156); background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(35,28,156,1) 0%, rgba(159,29,194,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%); cursor: move; } .pictureos { border-radius: 146px 146px 146px 146px; -webkit-border-radius: 146px 146px 146px 146px; -moz-border-radius: 146px 146px 146px 146px; } .imgs { -moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none; margin: 0 1em 1em 0; } .shadowimg { box-shadow: 13px 13px 56px 0px #663636; } .dfont { background: #121FCF; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #121FCF 0%, #FF006F 51%, #CF1512 48%); -webkit-background-clip: text; -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; size:100; } .regr { rgb(62%, 32%, 72%, 1); } .block-left{width:50%;height:800px;overflow:auto;float:left;} .block-right{width:50%;height:800px;overflow:auto;} </style> <div class="imgs"> <img src="https://i.ibb.co/kqDNTfr/IMG-20220830-134929-367.jpg" alt="" height="200" width="200" class="pictureos" class="shadowimg" align=left> <font size="1000" align=middle class="regr"><br>SunSearch</font> </div> <div class="information"> <br><br><br><br><br><br> <font size="200px">{htmlresult.replace('\n','<br />')}</font> </div> </body> </html>"
```

Comment: Экранируйте «лишние» фигурные скобки `… html {{ background …`

Comment: И кавычки тоже экранируйте `… <div class=\"imgs\"> …`

Comment: А ещё лучше не лепите всё в одну большую кашу, а разделите логические части html-кода на несколько переменных и потом собирайте их вместе (а ещё лучше использовать полноценный шаблонизатор, но это уже другая история)

Comment: Здраствуйте, видел в чужом коде подобный скрипт, по этому сделал все в кашу

Comment: ^ и ущё уберите f

Comment: @splash58 не надо убирать, тут подстановки питоновых переменных есть

Comment: @andreymal тогда будет ошибка со стилями в фигурных скобках, это же спецсивол для f строки

Comment: @splash58 об этом я и написал в первом комментарии)

Comment: чтобы не экранировать кавычки можно f"""...""" использовать